# No traceback for manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, traceback

Weird problem. I have a Django site that I run in two ways:

1. Through apache/wsgi on :80 normally
2. With `python manage.py runserver` on :8000 when testing

Through wsgi everything works fine, but using `runserver`, when I get to any error page (`debug = True`), the page loads halfway and then just keeps loading forever, without showing traceback.

Some notes about loading 'halfway':

- It seems to load to exactly the same point for the same error
- For a different error, it will be a different point (both a different part of traceback and a different file size according to Firebug)
- For a different browser, it will load to a different point (consistently the same point if the page is reloaded).
- An example: I have a ValueError now that loads to the first step in the traceback, at 'local vars', where `request` is loaded. In Firefox it consistently loads up to `SSH_CONNECTION`, whereas in Chrome is loads up to `SHELL` (which loads fine in Firefox).
- Server restarts have no effect.

Normal (non-error) pages load just fine. The console doesn't show anything special, just the request with code 500.

Comment: Anything printed on the console where `runserver` is running?

Comment: It (usually) shows the request with code 500, but no errors.

Comment: Did you try `curl` or `wget` on the local server?  They may show some more informative error messages.  Also try Chrome's "Inspect element" option to view the Network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a `pdb.set_trace()` somewhere in your code. I would guess in a `__unicode__` method or something that is being called during the rendering of the error page. This is predicated on the notion that output from the dev server is buffered.

Another (very likely) possibility is that you have an endlessly recursive call going on somewhere (quite possibly in a similar place as the aforementioned `set_trace` situation), but the recursive functionality is taking just long enough that you never see the `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error.

For example:

```
import time

def foo():
    time.sleep(.2)
    bar()

def bar():
    foo()

bar()
```

It's otherwise pretty difficult to make a Python program just hang, unless you do it on purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes sense, but I'm afraid I haven't used `set_trace` anywhere (I wasn't actually aware of it's existence until now).

Comment: @Mark - no problem. I just added another possibility to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15132

The workaround is to install "django-extensions" and werkezeug, and start the server with `manage.py runserver_plus`. This enhanced development server shows tracebacks by default among other niceties.